# Discord.js Interaction Already Replied error while sending Modal

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am developing a discord bot using Discord.js. I have created a function called sendModal(interaction) in one file and I am capturing events in another file.

I am facing the following error

[image: Error]

discord_method.js

```
async function sendModal(interaction) {
const modal = new ModalBuilder()
            .setCustomId('myModal')
            .setTitle('My Modal');


        const favoriteColorInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('favoriteColorInput')
            .setLabel("What's your favorite color?")
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Short);

        const hobbiesInput = new TextInputBuilder()
            .setCustomId('hobbiesInput')
            .setLabel("What's some of your favorite hobbies?")
            .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph);

        const firstActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(favoriteColorInput);
        const secondActionRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(hobbiesInput);

        modal.addComponents(firstActionRow, secondActionRow);

        await interaction.showModal(modal);
}
```

interactCreate.js

```
const DC = require("../methods/discord_methods")

module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction) {

        await interaction.deferReply()

         DC.sendModal(interaction)
},
};
```

I am following their [Official Documentation](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/modals.html#building-and-responding-with-modals) and I could not find another way to send this.

Any advice or help is appreciated!

Comment: In the question, you are showing the `sendModal` function in `../methods/discord_methods.js`, but in the `interactionCreate` event listener, you are calling a different function called `interactiveBtn`. Are the `sendModal` and `interactiveBtn` function the same? If not, can you add that function to the question as well?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I copy pasted the wrong method and error, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `deferReply()` is used to defer a response as a message by using `editReply()` later. As you want to show a modal, you can't use `deferReply()`.

Since your modal should show instantly, you can probably juste remove `await interaction.deferReply()` and it should make it

**Edit :** If your modal does not show instantly because of some data your need to retrieve before showing it, you can first use `deferReply()` until all your data is retrieved, then `edit()` to edit your reply with a message containing a button that will open your modal. Since all the data is already loaded, you can fill your modal within the button interaction and show it in less than the 3s required

Comment: As I read in the document, I need to send the reply within 3 secs, my program takes more than  secs that's I have to use interaction.deferReply().

Is there a way I can use deferReply() first and than invoke sendModal()?

Comment: As far as I know, deferReply can not be used to wait for a modal, i think that you'll have to deal with it :/

However, I'm wondering how your modal can take more than 3 seconds since it's only 3 TextInput, it should be less than a sec.

Have you tried removing `await interaction.deferReply()` and using `await DC.sendModal(interaction)` ?

Comment: Yes, The Modal will be dynamic, it will fetch the data from Airtable and display the questions accordingly.

Comment: Then I think that the only solution would be to load your questions and then ask for a new interaction to open your Modal (e.g with a button "Show me the question" that is bound to your first interaction reply message (Since you did `deferReply()`, you can edit your reply with that button). That way, you can open the modal within the 3s window as your question has already been loaded

Comment: Thank you so much, I will implement this and let you know the results

Comment: I know this is beyond the scope of ques, but I have been struggling with sending video files and document file, Can you please help with this ques as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74411178/discord-js-send-video-and-documents